# Does sharing App Hash through OTP have any drawbacks in terms of app security

Tags: android, security, hash

While implementing OTP for user verification in android app, i am using **SMS Retriever API** in order to bypass the SMS Read permission. In SMS Retriever API, we need a special format i.e **<#>** at the start of message & your **App Hash** at the end of message.

1. Is sharing app hash like this a safe way/ good practise or does it have any threats in terms of app security.
2. Is there anyway we can hide this **<#>** & **App Hash** when received at user end. Tried **\u200b\u200b** sending this instead of **<#>** but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview) docs

> When the user's device receives the SMS message, Google Play services uses the app hash to determine that the message is intended for your app, and makes the message text available to your app through the SMS Retriever API.

As it is clearly mentioned it is used by Google Play services so I dont think there should be any security concerns.